# How to get current location (latitude and longitude) and send it to an reverse geocoding API?

Tags: javascript, api, web-applications, location, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get my current latitude and longitude and passing it to a web API called OpenCage Geocoder API. This is what I have done:

```
// reverse geocoding
function geocode() {

let lat,long;
window.onload = function() {
      var startPos;
      var geoSuccess = function(position) {
            startPos = position;
             lat = startPos.coords.latitude;
             long = startPos.coords.longitude;
      };
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
  };


geoResponse = function(reponse)
{
   document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = response.results[17].toString();
};



let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q="+ lat +","+ long +"&key=00f711f73483427c8577e646aa2bf4bf&jsonp=geoResponse";
document.body.appendChild(script);


}
```

I'm new to coding, and I am a bit stuck. Is there any easier method to call this particular API, I'm pretty lost.
Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have modified and attached the snippet of your code for Reference! In your getResponse you received the param as reponse and in code you have called the response.results[17].toString() Which got undefined!

```js
        window.onload = function() {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = "https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q="+ lat +","+ long +"&key=00f711f73483427c8577e646aa2bf4bf&jsonp=geoResponse";
            document.body.appendChild(script);  

        });
      }

      geoResponse = function(reponse){
        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = reponse.results[0].formatted;
    }
```

```html
  <div id="address">
    </div>
```

Comment: For some reason, this isn't working. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @LakshJaisinghani In what reason? Did you tried the snippet in plain html!?